# Angularjs - Angular UI Grid: It's possible to filter dynamically dropdown options by rowentity values?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to filter a dropdown options using the rowEntity value.

```
$scope.data = [{
    'id_a': 1,
    'code': 1,
    'line': 'Line 1 '
}, {
    'id_a': 2,
    'code': 2,
    'line': 'Line 2'
}, {
    'id_a': 3,
    'code': 1,
    'line': 'Line 3'
}, {
    'id_a': 4,
    'code': 3,
    'line': 'Line 4'
}];


$scope.opts = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'A',
    code: 1
}, {
    id: 2,
    value: 'B',
    code: 2
}, {
    id: 3,
    value: 'C',
    code: 1
}, {
    id: 4,
    value: 'D',
    code: 1
}, {
    id: 5,
    value: 'E',
    code: 3
}, {
    id: 6,
    value: 'F',
    code: 2
}];

    $scope.columns = [{
    field: 'line',
    enableCellEdit: false,
    enableFiltering: false
}, {
    field: 'code',
    enableCellEdit: false,
    enableFiltering: false
}, {
    field: 'value',
    enableFiltering: false,
    width: 500,
    editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
    editDropdownIdLabel: 'id',
    editDropdownValueLabel: 'value',
    editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.opts
}];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    },
    columnDefs: $scope.columns
};
$scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.data;
```

What i'm trying to do is load an array in `editDropdownOptionsArray` and then dynamically filter this array using a value.

If i'm in 'Line 1' then can only appear the options that have the same 'code' value.

In this case 'Line 1' have the code '1' then the dropdowns options are 'A','C','D'

How can i do this? Using `cellFilter`?

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/viAeM50kPGpNVJ5rYT2w) with  the base code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works out for you, and feel free to accept it it does:

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KpBEzv64K2LvQtYlf9rx?p=preview)

1. Set your template:

   ```
   editableCellTemplate: 'dropdown.html'
   ```
2. Add `dropdown.html` to your project:

> ```
> <select ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" ng-options="item as item.value for
> item in col.colDef.editDropdownOptionsArray | filter : { code:
> row.entity.code}"></select>
> ```

3. Test:

[image]

Comment: That's a great solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

After the solution from KreepN i've made some upgrades in the code because i wasn't getting the value of the row when i choose one option.

I add `ui-grid-edit-dropdown` on select and that's solved the problem.

[Updated Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/48Ir9IXBWR4WiRsHVhaR)

Once again thank you KreepN for your solution.

Comment: Good on you for the extra mile there dude. I get to learn something too :) +1